# AutoMapper using EF Core persists and inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, ef-core-3.1

I am using

- .NET Core v3.1
- EF Core v3
- AutoMapper v9
- AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFrameworkCore v1.0.1

and I am trying to add polymorph entities.

I have the following entities:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Child1 : Base
{
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
}
```

And corresponding dtos

```
public abstract class BaseDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Child1Dto : BaseDto
{
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
}
```

I am registering them like that:

```
CreateMap<Base, BaseDto>()
   .IncludeAllDerived()
   .ReverseMap()
   .IncludeAllDerived();

CreateMap<Child1, Child1Dto>()
   .ReverseMap();
```

And also add do db context like that with discriminator:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Base>()
   .HasDiscriminator<string>("type")
   .HasValue<Child1>("child1");
```

After that I try to add a new entry to the database like that:

```
var dto = new Child1Dto()
{
    Name = "Name",
    Name2 = "Name2",
};

var addedOrInserted = db.Set<Base>().Persist(_mapper).InsertOrUpdate(dto);
```

But for that case, I get the following exception:

> Expression of type 'AutoMapper.EquivalencyExpression.EquivalentExpression`2[Child1]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'AutoMapper.EquivalencyExpression.IEquivalentComparer`2[Base]'

I think that this happens because the `InsertOrUpdate` is checking if the entity exists to check if an insert or an update should be performed.

Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: What database are you using?  May be better to create your tables in the database and then let the VS tools create you entity classes.

Comment: Hi @Flo,any updates about this case?

Comment: @Yinqiu not really i am a little bit busy the last days. But i shortly tested your solution and it seems to work. But i would like to do some further tests on it. It's not the optimal solutions, because i have to create one save method for each child.

Comment: I think it will be difficult.If you find the best solution, you can post it here and mark it as an answer, it will be helpful to those who have this problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be because you used `CreateMap<Child1,Child1Dto>().ReverseMap();` when registering.

Even if they are inheritance relationship, it is not possible to directly add `Child1Dto` to `Base`, I think it may be necessary to use `db.Set<Child1>`.

Try to add `public DbSet<Child1> Child1s { get; set; }`in your context.

Then in your controller:

```
     Child1Dto basedto = new Child1Dto() 
            { 
                Id = new Guid(), 
                Name = "Name", 
                Name2 = "Name2" 
            };
     context.Child1s.Persist(mapper).InsertOrUpdate(basedto); 
     context.SaveChanges();
```

Result:
[image]